# ios : Custom framework with multiple target pod integration issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods, gitlab, ios-frameworks, swift-custom-framework

We have developed a Custom framework in iOS which has multiple targets. Each target gives a different (Example SDK1,SDK2,SDK3) SDK. We have also uploaded the same on Github with below podspec.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      #1.
      s.name               = "CustomFramework"
      #2.
      s.version            = "1.0.1"
      #3.  
      s.summary         = "Sort description of 'CustomFramework' framework"
      #4.
      s.homepage        = "http://www.customframework.com"
      #5.
      s.license              = "MIT"
      #6.
      s.author               = "Test Author"
      #7.
      s.platform            = :ios, "10.0"
      #8.
      s.source              = { :git => "https://gitlab.com/xxxx/CustomFramework.git", :tag => "1.0.1" }
      #9.
      s.source_files     = "CustomFramework", "CustomFramework/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
 end
```

To add this sdk in project, we have written below code in pod file.

```
pod 'CustomFramework',:git=>'https://gitlab.com/xxxx/CustomFramework.git'
```

But it always fetch the SDK which are belongs to first target (SDK1).

**Is there any by which we can specify the schema name / target name (SDK1/ SDK2 / SDK3)which we required to fetch?**

Comment: What about doing subspecs? then, you do `pod 'CustomFramework/CustomVersion1`, :git=>...`,  `pod 'CustomFramework/CustomVersion2`, :git=>...` etc depending on your needs. Cf https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec

Comment: @Larme I have tried but its not working as when we write pod name 'CustomFramework' , it always take the first target.( SDK1) By doing subspecs we can add/remove specific files but we can not call specific target.